# Combine a dict of varied-length data frames into a single data frame, and pad with zeros to enforce dimensionality

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a collection of time Series in a `dict`:

```
my_dict = {
     ts_1 : df_1,
     ts_2 : df_2,
     ts_3 : df_3,
     ts_4 : df_4,
     ts_5 : df_5
}
```

...where each `df` is of the form:

```
       yr_mo    number
0   2014-12-01  2
1   2015-01-01  42
2   2015-02-01  7
3   2015-03-01  15
4   2015-04-01  18
```

I need to convert this `dict` of data frames into a single `df` of the form:

```
     2014-12-01    2015-01-01    2015-02-01    2015-03-01    2015-04-01
0        2             42            7            15             18
1.       7             44           33            38              9
2.       3              6           43             9              3
3.       8              3           77             3              9
4.       1              7           79             2             10
```

Since these time Series are of different length, I would like to pad the shorter time Series with zeros, so that the dimensionality is the same for each Series.

I have tried by doing the following:

```
df_collection = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='index')
```

...but this gives the incorrect format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the dictionary then remove the individual DataFrame indexes with [`droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) and add an index level for `yr_mo` with [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) then [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) the Series to go to wide format. Lastly, some cleanup to remove axis names and create default range index with [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
new_df = (
    pd.concat(my_dict)
        .droplevel(1).set_index('yr_mo', append=True)['number']
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .rename_axis(columns=None)
        .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

`new_df`:

```
   2014-12-01  2015-01-01  2015-02-01  2015-03-01  2015-04-01
0           0          29          19          38          39
1          28          41           5          25           0
2           3          21           0          35          13
3           7          26          33          23           0
4          10          47          39           0          17
```

---

Reproducible random sample Data:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import Generator, MT19937

bit_gen = MT19937(15)
rng = Generator(bit_gen)

r = list(range(5))
my_dict = dict(zip(r, [pd.DataFrame({
    'yr_mo': ['2014-12-01', '2015-01-01', '2015-02-01', '2015-03-01',
              '2015-04-01'],
    'number': rng.integers(1, 50, 5)
}).sample(frac=0.9, random_state=bit_gen, ignore_index=True) for _ in r]))
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. You were just missing the `.fillna(0)` at the end.

Comment: You could also do `.unstack(fill_value=0)`

Answer (score 2):

```
ts_gen = (ts.set_index('yr_mo') for ts in my_dict.values())

res = (
    pd.concat(ts_gen, axis=1,    # concatenate the time series as columns (dates are the index/rows)
              ignore_index=True) # via index alignment ('yr_mo')  
      .T        # transpose so the dates are columns
      .fillna(0)   # fill the missing dates values with zero
      .rename_axis(None, axis=1)  # remove the name of the column axis (which was 'yr_mo')
)
```

**Output**

```
from pandas import Timestamp 

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'yr_mo': [Timestamp('2014-12-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2015-02-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2015-03-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2015-04-01 00:00:00')],
 'number': [2, 42, 7, 15, 18]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'yr_mo': [Timestamp('2014-12-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2015-02-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2015-03-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2015-04-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp("2015-05-01")],
 'number': [2, 4, 2, 10, 18, 20]})

my_dict = {"ts_1" : df1, "ts_2" : df2}

>>> df1 

       yr_mo  number
0 2014-12-01       2
1 2015-01-01      42
2 2015-02-01       7
3 2015-03-01      15
4 2015-04-01      18


>>> df2

       yr_mo  number
0 2014-12-01       2
1 2015-01-01       4
2 2015-02-01       2
3 2015-03-01      10
4 2015-04-01      18
5 2015-05-01      20    # only different/extra date from df1 

>>> res

   2014-12-01  2015-01-01  2015-02-01  2015-03-01  2015-04-01  2015-05-01
0         2.0        42.0         7.0        15.0        18.0         0.0
1         2.0         4.0         2.0        10.0        18.0        20.0
```

Comment: I notice your approach padds to the right, while @HenryEcker 's padds to the left. Any reason?

Comment: What do you mean "padds to the right" vs "padds to the left" @Cybernetic ? Do you mean the column order? If so you can just add `sort=True` to concat like `pd.concat(ts_gen, axis=1, ignore_index=True, sort=True)` it's just because `unstack` sorts by default where `concat` does not.

Comment: @HenryEcker The time series can be placed so their final values are flush to the right, which puts their padded 0s to their left. Or vice versa. It makes a difference when it comes to training forecasting models.

Comment: @Cybernetic in both solutions, the missing values correspond to dates of one time series that are not present in the other. The time series are stacked via the alignment of the date indices.  Both solutions result in missing values  (which are then filled with 0) in the same positions, so they are padded the same way. What you are asking is the overall order of date columns, which is a different issue. You can change the order of the columns as you wish. The solutions are equivalent.

Comment: @HarryPlotter this IS the issue. I understand what is happening, and forecasting wth zeros at the end vs zeros at the beginning is not the same thing.

Comment: @Cybernetic Then just sort the dates columns as you wish after running one of the solutions. My point was that the locations of the missing values are the same and Henry's solution and mine are equivalent. If you ignore the date labels when forecasting, such that the order between them becomes important,  it's another story.